# Passing pointer from Microsoft Visual C++ to Fortran and back after changing code from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, 32bit-64bit

In Fortran a C function is called (compiled in Visual Studio 64 bit):

```
SUBROUTINE GET_PNTR

INTEGER*8 NXLOC(41)
REAL*4 WRX25I(41)

NXLOC(1) = IVRLOC( WRX25I(1) )

RETURN
END
```

With the C function defined as:

```
long long IVRLOC(var)
void *var;
{
    return var;
}
```

When I stop at the return statement, `var` is defined as
`FORTRAN_X64.exe!0x00007ff6de5b8074`.

- Converting the address to big endian gives 32758 -564428684
- Converting the address to little endian gives -159449088 1954569182

When I step out of the function only the last 4 bytes (-564428684 in this case) of the big endian are shown for the value of NXLOC(1). I'm not sure if this is right or not, but it seems like it can't be and since the next step to use the address fails that it is incorrect seems confirmed. From searching the web it seems like the value should be little endian, but that is not what I'm seeing.

What is going on?

The next step in the Fortran code, when the address is used, looks like:

```
PROGRAM USE_PTR

INTEGER*8 NXLOC(41)
REAL*4 XSLAM(41)

NX = 41
CALL VALOCX(NXLOC(1),XSLAM(1),NX)

RETURN
END
```

Where the C function looks like:

```
void VALOCX( nsloc, vals, ns)
float *nsloc[], vals[];
int *ns;
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<*ns; i++) {
        vals[i] = *nsloc[i];
    }
}
```

`nsloc` in this function now has the value
`0x00007ff6de5b3c00 {FORTRAN_X64.exe!CHKSUB} {0xffffffffde5b8074 {???}}` where only the last four bytes of the original variable address is recovered. I'm assuming I need to convert from big endian to little endian at some point, but my efforts so far only seem to add to my confusion.

Why doesn't "var" convert to the correct value when exiting IVRLOC so that it converts back to the correct value in VALOCX?

Comment: Why do you assume bigendian anything would be an issue here? It seems you are using MS Windows. Is this correct?

Comment: `IVRLOC` returns `long long`. Why should it make sense as `REAL*8` or did you mean `INTEGER*8`? Please show the Fortran source. Shouldn't there be a cast in C? Anyway, modern Fortran has `type(c_ptr)`, `integer(c_intptr_t)` and other stuff in `iso_c_binding`.

Comment: you're right about the real*8 it is actually integer*8, and yes this is code from 30-40 years ago. When I was trying to understand what was going on I did a search on the endiness of the values and found "The Intel x86 and AMD64 / x86-64 series of processors use the little-endian format" and "There isn't a standard function to do so (as in C standard, or POSIX standard). If your PC is a (Windows-style) PC running Intel, it is little-endian"

Comment: yes it is MS Windows

Comment: Therefore I do not see any reason for anything being related to bigendian here. You will need a [mcve]. Please note that it is usually good to remain on the server at least 5 minutes after posting a question to react to immediate comments that often appear.

Comment: Are you declaring IVRLOC as a function returning INTEGER*8 (or maybe INTEGER(c_intptr_t) ) on the Fortran side? If not, it's of type default integer which will likely be a 4-byte integer.

But, as mentioned by @VladimirF , we really need a MRE to be able to meaningfully help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not declaring `IVRLOC` as a function returning `INTEGER*8` (or maybe `INTEGER(c_intptr_t)` ) on the Fortran side, it's of type default integer which will likely be a 4-byte integer. Which could explain half of the original 8-byte value being set to zero due to the type mismatch.